Manjaro runs into disk problems: Pi problem or SD card problem?
I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B v2 running Manjaro with a Nextcloud server. The Nextcloud data directory (and pretty much only that) lies on an external hard disk attached by USB, nearly everything else (including eg. the directories for access and error logs) is on the micro SD card (Verbatim Premium 32MB) plugged into the Pi.
The system runs fine for a few dozen minutes afte boot, but the the operating system runs into some fundamental problem, apparently with the SD card.
Twice I have received information about a kernel panic on screen, it looked like this.

(The other instance had the same CPU, differing only in Kernel Offset and PHYS_OFFSET.)
I have run dmesg and it outputs repeated errors to the screen so fast I cannot follow, but dmesg > dmesg.log ends before the error occurs and running it through an SSH connection has the connection die before any relevant output is reached. Outputting to the external hard disk works, confirming that the issue is specific to the SD card. I don't know whether the SD card is faulty, whether the Pi's SD card connector has a problem, or whether it's down to something in the kernel that cannot deal with this SD card and connector.
dmesg says, at the point where everything fails:
[May21 16:15] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  +0.000026] [a18962d3] CMD< 26 0
[  +0.000016] [a18962d4] CMD  26 0
[  +0.000013] [a18962d5] REQ> 806ab988 0
[  +0.000013] [2189e1ea] IRQ< 400 0
[  +0.000012] [2189e1ec] IRQB 806aba50 400
[  +0.000013] [2189e1ed] FCM< 806ab988 806aba50
[  +0.000013] [2189e1ef] RSP  800 0
[...]
[  +0.000012] [618a8d19] CMD< 26 0
[  +0.000012] [618a8d1b] CMD  26 0
[  +0.000013] [618a8d1b] REQ> 8098b988 0
[  +0.000011] [62241276] TIM< 0 0
[  +0.000012] mmc0:>cmd op 38 arg 0x0 flags 0x49d - resp 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000, err 0
[  +0.000021] mmc0: =========== REGISTER DUMP ===========
[  +0.000007] mmc0: SDCMD  0x00008826
[  +0.000009] mmc0: SDARG  0x00000000
[  +0.000007] mmc0: SDTOUT 0x00bebc20
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDCDIV 0x00000008
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDRSP0 0x00000800
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDRSP1 0x00002640
[  +0.000009] mmc0: SDRSP2 0x7fffffff
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDRSP3 0x00024020
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDHSTS 0x00000000
[  +0.000007] mmc0: SDVDD  0x00000001
[  +0.000009] mmc0: SDEDM  0x00010801
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDHCFG 0x0000040e
[  +0.000008] mmc0: SDHBCT 0x00000006
[  +0.000007] mmc0: SDHBLC 0x00000001
[  +0.000008] mmc0: ===========================================
[  +0.000149] mmc_erase: erase error -110, status 0x0
[  +0.136051] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.104184] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101273] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101174] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101173] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101170] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.000113] mmc0: tried to HW reset card, got error -84
[  +0.000017] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2720321 op 0x3:(DISCARD) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  +0.101216] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101165] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101221] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101339] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101661] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101412] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101244] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.000179] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 267602 starting block 3718072)
[  +0.000035] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p2, logical block 3593072
[...]
[  +0.000376] mmc0: card 0001 removed
[  +0.000559] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_wait_block_bitmap:574: comm fstrim: Cannot read block bitmap - block_group = 7, block_bitmap = 165
[  +0.000658] Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p2-8.
[  +0.000225] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_journal_check_start:84: comm kworker/u12:0: Detected aborted journal
[  +0.000132] JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for mmcblk0p2-8.
[  +0.000211] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock
[  +0.000010] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  +0.000008] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): ext4_do_writepages: jbd2_start: 922 pages, ino 267602; err -30
[  +0.005715] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): FAT read failed (blocknr 16)
[  +0.214935] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101150] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.102784] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.103711] mmc0: previous command never completed.
[  +0.101209] mmc0: previous command never completed.

How do I figure out whether I need to fix something in software, replace the Pi or replace the SD card?
